# Why can't I use an operator like plus sign to concatenate strings?

Tags: language-design, history, objective-c, strings

Why in Objective-C we should be typing explicit references to methods like stringByAppendingString to concatenate strings, when in some other languages we can use operators for that?

For example, Java and C++ let us just concatenate strings in a similar fashion to the way we make our programs add two numbers.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)**

Comment: @gnat I don't see how this question isn't a good fit for this site. I'm not asking a question related to an API, I'm asking a question about a programming language. I'm not asking for a solution to a problem, either. But if I'm wrong, please tell me why.

Comment: "curious as to why Apple thought" -> ask Apple, we're not their customer support

Comment: @gnat i don't see it any different than "why can't I do X in C#?" or "why does .Net do Y" and have Jon Skeet answer...

Comment: well the most likely answer you can get in questions like that is probably an [opinion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491) that it's because Objective C is a ["thin layer of _Smalltalk_ on top of C"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/147382/31260)

Comment: @gnat: Actually, the string concatenation operator in Smalltalk is `,`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag one can probably speculate that this operator wasn't "copied from" Smalltalk because `,` is already taken in C. Or maybe because it was considered "too fat" to fit into _thin layer_ mentioned above. etc...

Comment: @gnat - I get the impression that you think the answer to this question is primarily opinion based due to all of the apparent speculation about the language....

Comment: @GlenH7 look at the answers it already got - pure speculation ("because addition is commutative", gimme a break). There seem to be a seed of a reasonable [tag:history] question buried somewhere deep in there, but in current form it seems to be just a honeypot for senseless guesses

Comment: In objective-C, there are strings, mutable strings, attributed strings. With different behaviours. You can add to a string by using a C printf style format string. You can add path components with some built-in cleverness to build  paths to files and so on. And there is only _one_ '+' character.

Answer (score 6):

`+` is the symbol for *addition*. *Concatenation* is not addition. Addition is commutative (`a + b == b + a`), concatenation isn't (`"Hello" + "World" != "World" + "Hello"`).

Using `+` for concatenation is just wrong. Other languages use other operators for that reason, e.g. Haskell uses `++`, IMP, Perl and PHP use `.`, Ada and Visual Basic use `&`, PL/I uses `||`, Standard ML uses `^`, Smalltalk uses `,`, and Fortress has three different string concatenation operators `“Hello” ∥ “World”` (simple string concatenation), `“Hello” ||| “World”` (string concatenation with whitespace in between the two strings unless one of them is empty), and the juxtaposition operator for strings is overloaded as an alias for `|||`: `“Hello” “World”`.

By the way: I highly doubt Apple is responsible for this decision. String concatenation is such an important operation that I am pretty sure it was added long before Apple took over development of Objective-C, most likely even before it was used at NeXT.

Comment: You are missing the point. The question should be better named: why are the method calls enforced instead of an operator, be it +, ++ or something similar. I don't think that the question itself is about the semantics of +

Comment: The question *explicitly* mentions addition.

Comment: No, it explicitly mentions + operator. By convention, it is used for addition, I agree, but not all additions are commutative: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833270/rings-with-noncommutative-addition so your point about commutativity is debatable. Even your answer states that various languages have shortcuts for concatenation, usually operators. So, again, the question seems to be about the missing shortcut if you ask me.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea thanks for that link. Refreshing to see math folks debunking myths used by programmers to "justify" their beliefs. Next thing we'll probably see is someone claiming that naive set theory is consistent, as a "proof" for some tiny puny concept

Comment: @gnat As programmers, we use quite a lot of simplified math results or we abuse some properties. Binary representation of floating point numbers is not identical with real world numbers, yet we're still using them in our day to day programming. BigDecimal is only used where precision is required. But I'll stop being offtopic, sorry for that :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea yeah I am also comfortable when simplification is justified, like in your example with approximating real numbers. It doesn't look like it here though. That statement you criticized, it could be just spelled differently, to avoid misleading readers. "One can assume that people expect commutative operation when they see plus sign" - it would look less impressive, and would reveal an assumption open to challenge, but it would be at least accurate

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, in math, + is addition. However, in some programming languages, the + operator takes on a meaning that depends on the context in which it is used. For example, in Javascript, if we have a line that says var a = b + c, if b and c are integers, then the Web browser will add b and c together. If, however, b and c are strings, then the Web browser will concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages, the concatenation operator is just **syntactic sugar**. For example, in C#:

```
var a = b + c;
```

and:

```
var a = string.Concat(b, c);
```

are compiled to the same Intermediary Language code if `b` and `c` are strings: `+` is here just to make developers' life easier.

Syntactic sugar might be nice, but it also means that the company developing the language should spend time:

- Redesigning the language to include the specific syntactic sugar feature; this alone is an extremely complicated task.
- Modifying the compiler so it can deal with the new syntax.
- Documenting the new behavior, including the fact that `+` is now commutative in some cases, but not in others and translating the documentation in every supported language.
- Dealing with all the edge cases; for instance, what is the result of `"123" + 4`, and what is the result of `1 + "234"`?
- Changing all the IDEs to support the new syntax.
- Thoroughly testing the compiler and the IDEs.

Adding such feature also means that there would be inevitably three types of developers:

- The ones who will understand that the operator is syntactic sugar and how is it translated by the compiler,
- The ones who won't know the internals, but know how to use the operator and what it involves,
- The ones who won't know the internals and ask questions such as: “I believe string *addition* is slow, so I will rewrite my entire code base to use `string.Concat` instead. Am I on the right track?”

Thus, **instead of making everyone's lives easier, you are just spending dozens of thousands of dollars developing a feature which only obfuscates the language**.

This is also why languages tend to use as few keywords as possible. More keywords means more opportunities for bugs and unclear situations, and more difficult to learn language with more rules.

Comment: question was recently [edited to focus on the history of Objective C](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/287800/revisions "Rev 2"), would you mind updating the answer to account for that?